# bootstrap button css not loading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded twitter bootstrap and most of the css seems to be working, but I cannot get the buttons to render correctly. I am just getting default buttons. Below is some test html I am using:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "container">
            <form>
                <button type = "button" class = "bnt bnt-primary"> My Button </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why am I not getting the styling for the buttons?

Comment: try this <input type="button" class="btn" value="Here" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're swapping `btn` with `bnt`, which won't render.

Try:

```
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <form>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"> My Button </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/YuURs/

Answer (score 1):

You wrote bnt, it's btn

Try this :

```
<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary"> My Button </button>
```